# Should we approve suggested edits that just remove thanks?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

During a review I saw severals time the same [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978655/john?tab=profile) that just remove "Thanks in advance".

After some hesitation I accepted this [suggestion review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9076748), but sometimes in the same situation I had rejected some with the reason `no improvement whatsoever`

In this case, I looked to the user suggestions [history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978655/john?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and there is a lot of such edits :

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9088961
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9088960
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9088911
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9088909
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9088732
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9088716
- ...

Considering the count of thanks removing edits, I guess the user doesnot read the question, even partially ?
Some of them were approved, others were rejected.

I feel these edits are correct, but they improve really not much the post.

What should be the correct way to process such reviews ?
Is it a correct behaviour for a user to makes hundreds of such edits ?

Comment: @apaul34208 : I think it is closed but a bit different because the user makes hundreds of those edits.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would reject those edits. One of the following must be true:

- Nothing else is wrong with these posts that needs to be edited.
- The editor isn't bothering to check for other things that can be improved.

A simple "thanks in advance" does not get in the way of the rest of the question when it's all the way at the end of a post (unlike salutations at the beginning), so I don't think it's worth suggesting an edit *only* to remove a "thanks."

I could understand if people removed "thanks in advance" once in a while when they happened upon it while answering questions, but to search for the phrase and remove it in bulk seems a bit excessive. That's wasting the time of suggested edit reviewers.

Comment: And I thought that any edit that makes a post better in whatever way (be it removing fluff, fixing the tags, fixing typos), even if it ignores other, maybe bigger issues, should be accepted...

Comment: @CodeCaster It's debatable whether this is really improving anything. However, people really should be fixing everything that needs to be fixed when they edit a post. Fixing one minor typo on a post filled with formatting and spelling errors should be rejected.

Comment: @CodeCaster Users < 2k should make as meaningful an edit as possible, because of the hassle of the review queue. While users > 2k should also strive to make as meaningful an edit as possible, editing rampages and minor corrections are generally alright.

Comment: Sure, compared to a typo or an irrelevant tag, "thanks" is just a minor inconvenience. Is _"When <2K users submit a suggested edit, they should try to fix everthing that needs fixing with the post"_ documented somewhere?

Comment: @CodeCaster No, it's just a general opinion shared by a collection of people, like many of the other "rules" we go by.

Comment: @Kevin I am one of those people, but wouldn't it be nice to be able to present it to people who are suggesting such edits? The "Too minor" reason was removed for a reason, and you cannot say edits that just remove "Thanks" aren't an improvement. They _do_ improve the post.

Comment: I would approve an edit like this, but, if i found a user that was actively searching out these kinds of posts and fixing them without fixing everything in the post, i would approve it, and then consider flagging one of the posts and explaining the situation to a moderator. We, the community, can't do anything about the situation, so if anything needs to be done about it, get a moderator involved.

Comment: Rejecting a few of their edits is unlikely to get the point across effectively. The individual edits are improvements and generally are valid (unless other major problems aren't also fixed), but the way it is being done is the problem.