# How to stop minor edit binging? (Warm Regards RAMPAGE!!!)

Tags: discussion

Going through the edit queue today, I ran into the same user making the same edit over and over - only removing some form of "warm regards" from posts. I imagine s/he is hunting these down purposefully and editing.

Generally I would just reject ([as per this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302300/should-we-approve-suggested-edits-that-just-remove-thanks)) However, as they are well below the 2K threshold, this seriously bogs down the edit queue. In fact, further investigating the user shows that this is [literally the only thing they have ever done on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6042828/smit-patel?tab=reputation)

Without DMing, it is hard to educate the user that this should not be done. Is there any way to throttle/educate?

Warm Regards,

Chris

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if this is a scheme to build up reputation for system abuse...

Comment: Could try chatting with the user: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/6042828

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Don't seems like, since the user only has 3 votes.

Comment: @Rizier123 True, but that doesn't rule out possible future abuse. I have a tendency to assuming things are scams though.

Comment: I've been inspired to Skip through the review queue and Reject and Edit each of this user's suggestions. Of course I'm going to do it properly, so maybe they'll get the message.

Comment: @Laurel You can get the list of their suggested edits here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/6042828/smit-patel?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: What is 'DMing'? "Without DMing, it is hard to educate the user that this should not be done": [Ping an editor for repeated invalid editing behavior](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273268/ping-an-editor-for-repeated-invalid-editing-behavior)

Comment: Feels like edit sprees are increasingly common. We really need to [rate limit edit suggestions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits).

Comment: @S.L.Barth that feature request is only three years old; obviously we need to wait another three to five years before it's implemented ;)

Comment: @RadLexus I meant direct message - I just sent them a chat as per Alexander's suggestion, we'll see what happens

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes.. and it's even been bountied in that time. Edits just don't seem to be very high on SO's priority list.